# Whats the simplest way for a python program to check if a file is valid LaTeX

Tags: compiling, tex-core

### Problem Statement:

Given a file with some arbitrary name and possibly incorrect extension, how to programatically and/or using command line tools figure out if it is a LaTeX file?

### Context:

I was playing around with data mining source files in ArXiV for some hobby ML work but I ran into a problem.

The source files are packaged as big tar.gz blobs in amazon s3 which you can download after paying a fee and decompress using tar -xvf,

Once decompressed you get a folder structure

```
FolderNameWithMonth/
    file1.gz
    file2.gz
    file3.pdf
    file4.gz
    file5.pdf 
    ...
```

So basically when someone uploads a pre-print to ArXiV, if they upload nothing other than a pdf, then their file will be a pdf in that folder i described above. If they upload a collection of files (source.tex, images, etc...) it gets zipped into a gzip.

But here's the kicker, some of those gzip files I listed above, aren't actually gzip files at all! They just HAPPEN to be named "filename.gz" and if you were to open them up with a notepad (or any other text editor of your choice) you'd be shocked to find they are actually LaTeX files. They've merely been misnamed with the .gz extension.

So that leads to our problem, how do programatically weed out the gzip imposters here (i.e. check if their contents are secretly valid LaTeX, and therefore don't need to be unzipped).

### Some Ideas On a Solution:

1. Given a file you could try to unzip it, if that fails, then try to compile it (what compiler should I use?), if that also fails then the file is probably some other weird format that I haven't considered. But compiling each file is a very expensive operation if you have a lot of files
2. Is there a key word that one can search for? I was thinking to scan the file as a string of characters and look for `\end{document}` but it turns out the normal gzips sometimes might have that in their text as well so this is less effective than I hoped.
3. Send angry email to arxiv to label their file extensions correctly but they are already very stressed and underpaid so this might not be an effective strategy.

Comment: you can use `file` or `gunzip` to check if the files are gzipped (but that seems off topic here really as it is unrelated to testing for latex)

Comment: No matter which keyword you look for, there is always the chance that your compression algorithm just happens to preserve it. But you can filter out gzip files by looking at the first three bytes: If they are 0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08 then it can not be a LaTeX file and is almost certainly a gzip file.

Comment: You might want to look into arXiv's AutoTeX, it's decent at guessing the TeX flavour.

Comment: `file` as David mentioned will check the first few bytes as Marcel mentioned; and `gunzip` will tell you whether the file can be successfully un-gzipped, which in some sense is what you actually care about. (Even if one didn't have these two tools, I imagine one can probably get good results simply by looking at the distribution of the file's bytes in the 0–255 range. When passed through compression like gzip, I imagine the bytes will be more evenly distributed, while with an actual LaTeX file the distribution will be much more uneven, even for say Unicode documents in non-Latin scripts.)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger this idea seemed to work but i ran into a problem, I found a file which had a .gz extension the first few bytes from the head came out as ```xxd 1001.0649.gz | head
00000000: 1f8b 0808 effb 424b 0203 5443 5332 3030 ``` I saw that "1f8b" and assumed it must be a gzip, but tar failed to open the file, and upon opening it with vim, it turned to be valid LaTeX (i even opened it successfully with a TeX editor), what might've caused that to happen?

Comment: The file in question is the source file of this paper: https://arxiv.org/format/1001.0649, curiously when downloaded from the ArXiV main page it doesn't come with a .gz extension, and running the exact same code on this file yields: ```  xxd 1001.0649 | head 00000000: 5c64 6f63 756d 656e 7463 6c61 7373 5b70 ```. Exact same file, totally different binary headers

Comment: This is turning into an operating systems question, it looks like there something complicated that happens when vim tries to "read" a file

Comment: @frogeyedpeas If the file is gzip comppressed but not a tar archive, vim extracts it automatically. (It even compresses it again when you are changing something.)